# Google Merchants Center "robots.txt on the server is unreachable"

Tags: merchant-account, google-ads-api, google-merchant-center

[image]I have about 6 month using google merchants center and google ads.

and today I get this issue "

> robots.txt on the server is unreachable

"
I know this file is not required, and this not exist in my server, but i have created it, but google continue showing the same message.

I have another site, with similar data and this is working fine.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL path to the file to confirm it is reachable from your browser.
`https://www.yoursite.com/robots.txt`

Comment: If you uploaded it today there will be some lag time within the Merchant Center. If you don't see a change in 2-3 days you can reach out to Google support and request they trigger a crawl to reach the file.

Comment: no, i upload the image here in stackoverflow jaja, but i have uploaded the feed... six month ago... and today appears this issue..

Comment: Google recently crawled your site and found the robots.txt was not reachable. If you added the robots.txt today there will be a delay before the warning is removed from the Merchant Center.